# How do I log into Discord?

Tags: login, registration, discord

Every time I go to Discord, it asks me to claim an account. I click the button to claim the account and enter my username & password, but it says the email is already taken. That's because I already have a Discord account! So how do I actually log into Discord instead of always registering? There is no login button! It always forces you to register, even if you already have an account!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went to User Settings (Gear Icon at bottom) > Logout > Logout > then was able to log in, then click on the Discord link from the original web site to 'accept invitation' to that site's channel.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you're using the discordapp.com website instead of the application.

I'd recommend using the application but for logging into the website you can go to discordapp.com then at the top right click Login which will take you to your login page where you can enter your email and password.

[image: Discord Login]