# How to get past Discord's "This is an unclaimed account"?

Tags: discord

There are so many times I have use a Discord channel, but next time I went to some website and click on that same Discord icon again, it says

> This is an unclaimed account. Claim it before it's lost [Claim Account]

and I click on it, and Google Chrome fills in my email and password, and I click "Next", and it shows "Email already registered".

I have never had any other website that had so many issues with this.  What is it about "unclaimed account" and then "email already registered", which seem like an infinite contradictory loop. How can this be solved?

Comment: This seems to be the only answer. A sad one though. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/125672/298168

Answer (score 3):

Ok, down on your Discord Account profile  "While Viewing on the web"  bottom left corner you will see your profile pic is not you,  click it,  and select switch account , and log in,  thats it,

this just happens when youve clicked on a server invite that expired whilst using the web discord thats all,

so switch account and log in on your normal account,  cause the web is in annonymous mode thats all.

Answer (score -1):

When you first enter the server and it asks for your handle, don't do that and instead click the link that says "Already have an account"